# What is the alternative for side inputs in apache beam

Tags: apache-kafka, streaming, apache-beam, lookup-tables, beam-sql

I am trying to join multiple kafka streams & lookups using Apache Beam. Im using side inputs for handling lookup tables and everything worked out in direct runner. But, when i try to run it in spark mode or flink mode, i learnt that side inputs are not supported. These are few links of the Jira Bugs.

> http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/beam-user/201605.mbox/%3C573EFC2F.6000708@nanthrax.net%3E
> https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-6131
>
> https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2112

Is there a way to use side input or a work around for this ?

Can i use stateful processing for this? I know the state is available per window per key,but still is there a tweak to use it in a different way ?

Can i use a caching db like memcached and fetch data while processing every record?

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There is a alternative idea called seekable join in BeamSQL. It's similar to sideinput join but it just require one side of join input is seekable [1](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/extensions/sql/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/sql/BeamSqlSeekableTable.java#L35).

So it will depends on if you can construct a table to implement `seek` API (underlying implementation could just be a API call).